# Compare two tables and find the missing combinations

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 columns in my main table.

1. Score ( 0-99,100-110)
2. rate  (5-9 ,10-15)
3. location (A, B)

And I have all the combinations of those (2 * 2 * 2 = 8 combinations)

Below are the combinations in my main table

```
score     rate   location
----------------------------
 0-99      5-9     A
100-110    5-9     A
 0-99     10-15    A
100-110   10-15    A
0-99       5-9     B
100-110    5-9     B
0-99      10-15    B
100-110   10-15    B
```

I have another table with the actual data. I want to find out all the missing combinations in the actual table. How to find those missing combinations and append to the actual table with value as '0' in the column?

Actual data

```
score     rate   location  value 
---------------------------------
 0-99     10-15    A         3
100-110   10-15    A         6
0-99      10-15    B         1
```

Expected output

```
 score     rate   location  value 
------------------------------------
 0-99        5-9     A           0   
 0-99        10-15   A           3
100-110     10-15    A           6
100-110      5-9     B           0
0-99        10-15    B           1
100-110     5-9      A           0
100-110    10-15     B           0
0-99       10-15     B           0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `CROSS JOIN` do generate a Cartesian product for `score`,`rate`,`location` columns, make the full table.

then do `OUTER JOIN` base on the `CROSS JOIN` table.

```
create table t(
  score varchar(50),
  rate varchar(50),
  location  varchar(50),
  value  int
);

insert into t values ('0-99','5-9','A',2);   
insert into t values ('0-99','10-15','A',3);
insert into t values ('100-110','10-15','A',6);
insert into t values ('100-110','5-9','B',7);
insert into t values ('0-99','10-15','B',1);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT  
  s.score,
  r.rate,
  l.location,
  coalesce(t1.value,0)
FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT score FROM T) s
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT rate FROM T) r
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT location FROM T) l
LEFT JOIN t t1 on s.score = t1.score and t1.rate = r.rate and t1.location = l.location
ORDER BY  l.location
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/17b8e/10/0)**:

```
|   score |  rate | location | coalesce |
|---------|-------|----------|----------|
|    0-99 | 10-15 |        A |        3 |
|    0-99 |   5-9 |        A |        2 |
| 100-110 | 10-15 |        A |        6 |
| 100-110 |   5-9 |        A |        0 |
|    0-99 | 10-15 |        B |        1 |
|    0-99 |   5-9 |        B |        0 |
| 100-110 | 10-15 |        B |        0 |
| 100-110 |   5-9 |        B |        7 |
```

Comment: ,I have updated the my actual data.In this scenario how do i get the desired solution?

Comment: @user8545255 your actual data didn't have `rate = 5-9` why would you expect get the  `rate = 5-9`?  Is there any table can `join` with it or it was hard code?