# Identify the missing combinations by comparing two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, greenplum

I have 3 columns in my main table.

1. Score ( 0-99,100-110)
2. rate  (5-9 ,10-15)
3. location (A, B)

And I have all the combinations of those (2 * 2 * 2 = 8 combinations)

Below are the combinations in my main table

```
score     rate   location
----------------------------
 0-99      5-9     A
100-110    5-9     A
 0-99     10-15    A
100-110   10-15    A
0-99       5-9     B
100-110    5-9     B
0-99      10-15    B
100-110   10-15    B
```

I have another table with the actual data. I want to find out all the missing combinations in the actual table. How to find those missing combinations and append to the actual table with value as '0' in the column?

Actual data

```
score     rate   location  value 
---------------------------------
 0-99     10-15    A         3
100-110   10-15    A         6
0-99      10-15    B         1
```

Expected output

```
 score     rate   location  value 
------------------------------------
 0-99        5-9     A           0   
 0-99        10-15   A           3
100-110     10-15    A           6
100-110      5-9     B           0
0-99        10-15    B           1
100-110     5-9      A           0
100-110    10-15     B           0
0-99       10-15     B           0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two tables and find the missing combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52044872/compare-two-tables-and-find-the-missing-combinations)

Comment: @Guillaume There is change in actual data.

Comment: @user8545255 your actual data didn't have rate = 5-9 why would you expect get the rate = 5-9? Is there any table can join with it or it was hard code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your actual data and expect result `score`,`rate`,`location` columns value seem to fixed, so you can use `UNION ALL` to let `score`,`rate`,`location` be tables.

`CROSS JOIN` to generate a Cartesian product for `score`,`rate`,`location` Union tables, make the full table.

Then do `OUTER JOIN`

```
create table t(
  score varchar(50),
  rate varchar(50),
  location  varchar(50),
  value  int
);


insert into t values ('0-99','10-15','A',3);   
insert into t values ('100-110','10-15','A',6);
insert into t values ('0-99','10-15','B',1);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT  
  s.score,
  r.rate,
  l.location,
  coalesce(t1.value,0)
FROM 
(
  SELECT '0-99' score
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '100-110'
) s
CROSS JOIN
(
  SELECT '10-15' rate
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '5-9'
) r
CROSS JOIN
(
  SELECT 'A' as "location"
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B'
) l
LEFT JOIN t t1 on s.score = t1.score and t1.rate = r.rate and t1.location = l.location
ORDER BY  l.location
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2f70d/7/0)**:

```
|   score |  rate | location | coalesce |
|---------|-------|----------|----------|
|    0-99 | 10-15 |        A |        3 |
|    0-99 |   5-9 |        A |        0 |
| 100-110 | 10-15 |        A |        6 |
| 100-110 |   5-9 |        A |        0 |
| 100-110 |   5-9 |        B |        0 |
|    0-99 | 10-15 |        B |        1 |
| 100-110 | 10-15 |        B |        0 |
|    0-99 |   5-9 |        B |        0 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Use left join with maintable and actualtable then apply case when with value column

```
select t.score,t.rate,t.location, case when value is null then 0 else value end as value 
from t left join t1
on t.score=t1.score and t.rate=t1.rate 
and t.location=t1.location
```

Comment: it gives me column ambiguity error.Have you tried this on your machine?